Add Component Java Swing
Good,
I have a custom component that extends JPanel. I add it to the Netbeans palette and everything works ok. I have added an addContainerListener and I have filled the componentAdded method but it does not work. When I drag a component from the palette to my custom component, it does nothing. How can I implement this function?
How can I implement this function?
